# Constraint value for Rust types

Tags: variables, types, rust, constraints, assign

In Rust, is it possible to define constraints for types?
Similar to constraints in database.

Example: Having an email type where only a valid email could be assigned
Example: Having a sex type where only `"male"` or `"female"` could be assigned

Example to be more clear:

```rust
type email = string;
/// Do something here to constrain the type to only accept valid emails assigned to it.

let my_mail:  email = "something@domain.com"  // -> OK
let my_mail2: email = "something"  // -> Error
```

I would like to know if this is possible not only for struct members.

Comment: you can define a function `fn set_mail(mail: &str) -> Result<(), ()>` and return an error if it does not fit your requirements? I don't get your question though.

Comment: Or use a newtype that can only be accessed through methods that check the value?

Comment: Note: for the second example, that's what `enum`s do.

Comment: @Jmb Creating a function seems to be what I'm looking for, it would be similar to a setter in a class based language then.

Answer (score 1):

You can do that by defining wrappers around your basic types, and checking your requirements when instantiating the wrapper.

For email addresses an example could be:

```rust
pub struct Email<'a>{
    // Private by default, so no one can access or edit it
    address: &'a str
};

impl<'a> Email<'a>
{
    pub fn new(address: &'a str) -> Result<Self, ()>
    {
        if is_valid_email(address) {
            Ok(Self{address})
        } else {
            Err(()) // Invalid email address
        }
    }

    // Provides read-only access to the raw address.
    pub fn get_address(&self) -> &'a str
    {
        self.address
    }
}
```

Then, anywhere you need a valid email, you simply take `Email` as argument confident in the knowledge that no one can create an `Email` with an invalid address.

Comment: You can even implement [`Deref<Target = &'a str>`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/ops/trait.Deref.html) so that one can use `&email` everywhere a (non-mutable) string is expected.

Comment: Is it possible to do this without structs too?

Comment: You could do something similar to enums or use tuple struct (`struct Email<'a>(&'a str)`). However, you can't really get around wrapping the `str` in something if you want the type system to ensure you get a valid email.

Comment: I tried your example code on the playground and it doesn't seem to work as expected https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=4b8232afd65a7b3793bcb4a8236467e5 I thought that on `Err` the email would be empty.

Comment: You have to use `Email::new("test")` to check whether the email is valid: [playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=f0c1bffec296d9888c192461a6c986d5). It will then return `Err(())`, which means you don't have a valid email. If you instantiate the struct directly (`Email{address="test"}`) you are circumventing the check. When I said no one could create an invalid `Email` that didn't include you, since you have full control to do anything to the struct, including validating an invalid email.

Answer (score 0):

There's a crate to do validations on structs: https://github.com/Keats/validator